# 5-color graph and minor

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colouring

We have a 5-color graph **G** without 5-clique. The question is: is there a minor **H** of **G** that is a 5-clique? [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) the minor definition.

With "5-color graph **G**" I mean $\chi (G)=5$.

Comment: Assuming "a 5-color graph G" means that $\chi(G) = 5$, I think so based on the $t = 5$ case of the Hadwiger conjecture, which Wikipedia says is known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory).